# Difference between ifconfig and ifquery output

Tags: 14.04, networking, interface, network-bonding

Is there a way of cleaning up the ifquery state so that it reflects the underlying devices? Rather than just the descriptors that are used to maintain the locks?

```
$ ifquery --state
bond0.100=bond0.100
bond0=bond0
eth3=eth3
eth1=eth1
eth0=eth0
```

I have removed the interface using the sysfs but it is still remaining in the ifquery state table.

```
$ ifconfig bond0
bond0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifquery --list
```

Shows the current interfaces that are picked up in your /etc/network/interfaces file in the order they will get picked up. This does not give an indication of the currently running interfaces.

```
ifquery --state
```

Shows the interfaces in some kind of order, it is unclear as of the time of writing, what drives that order.

The file `/run/network/ifstate` seems to maintain the order that the interaces were started. Each time an interface is started (by ifup) it is appended to the end of the list. When it is shut down (by ifdown) it will be removed from the list.

```
ifconfig <interface>
```

This will go to the device itself and make the queries directly, it does not maintain any state of the overall operating system. If interfaces are brought up using ifconfig then it will not be maintained in the state table.

The relevant package is: `ifupdown`